# SDK location not found error when using gradle import in Eclipse

Tags: macos, sdk, gradle

I am trying to import the sample from this link:

https://github.com/badlogic/theplanethatcouldntflygood

After I unzip the file, I try to import it as a gradle project, but I keep getting this error:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'theplanethatcouldntflygood-master'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I then attempted to add my sdk location to the ANDROID_HOME environment :

export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk

However, this did not fix the error. All the other questions I found on stack overflow related to this error seems to be with Android Studio, but I am having this issue in Eclipse.

All my software downloads are completely up to date since I just downloaded them today. I checked to see if there were any other updates required, and there isn't. I obtained the Eclipse extension for Gradle from this link:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

I am currently running on OS X Version 10.9.3.

I searched for answers on git hub to see if anyone else was having similar issues with this code but I couldn't find anything, so I am likely doing something very wrong. Almost all recommendations with Android Studio were to add the sdk location to the ANDROID_HOME environment, so I am lost as to what I should do to fix this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that eclipse has problems with reading environment variables. Have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/28344/path-env-variable-on-mac-os-x-and-or-eclipse, maybe will help You.

Answer (score 5):

I found this frustrating, too! Especially since adding the ANDROID_HOME didn't seem to help.

What worked for me was creating a file named local.properties with the contents being:

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
```

Save the local.properties file in the root directory of the project (in the same folder as gradlew, gradlew.bat, etc.).